# Transfer android device screenshot to remote PC using WIFI

Tags: android

I developed an android app which displays info on a large screen continuously, and staff members are in another room, we want to get screenshots remotely.
The device and PC are connected via WIFI, so what tools are available to implement this feature? or should I programming from scratch?

Comment: Unclear what that feature would be.

Comment: @greenapps When press "screen capture" button on a PC application, we could view the current large screen's image.

Comment: How is the Android device connected to the large screen? Strange you give so little info.

Comment: HDMI data line.  android device is an android TV box.

Comment: @greenapps I tried teamviewer, which is a remote software, but the operation of screen capture cannot be automatically done.

Comment: Are you able to get a screenshot on the Android device itself with code?

Comment: Yes, guided by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot

Comment: how to respond PC command and send the stored image is difficult for me :(

Comment: Those solutions take screenshots of just the app. Not of the whole sceen. Is this what you want? Have you tried those solutions?

Comment: Yes, only app's screen is needed.

Comment: Why waiting for a command? The app could continuouisly take a screenshot and transfer that to the pc.

Comment: your suggestion make things easier, thanks, so the problem is how to transfer file to pc?

Comment: There are so many examples where an Android client app sends a file to a java server on pc. Or to a socket server on pc or to a webserver on pc. You did not give info what kind of pc application you had in mind.

Comment: Ok,  I  already have an idea and I will try it,  Thank you for your patience！